# AngularFire/Firestore Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Today after a simple deploy for adjusts (without install new features) my angularfire application stay lot delay. When checked the console log see this message, in login screen, without any operation or request.

Somebody can give some trick?

```
Firestore (4.9.0) 2018-05-22T22:05:09.569Z: FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Quota exceeded.
Firestore (4.9.0) 2018-05-22T22:04:17.606Z: Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after unistall old unused functions

npm uninstall firabase-functions

Comment: i am using angularjs, please give me an advise

Comment: @Huy - Logarit I never used angularjs but you can try something like firebase deploy --only hosting or only deploy --only hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same error in angularfire 2. It looks like there are two possible options to solve this issue

1) User firebase cloud functions. Move your code there and call the function from angular. Retrieve the data.

2) Write a python script and execute it using tools like PyCharm.